# Magento 2: "Empty option" for programmatically populated select attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, select

I have a product attribute dropdown select box that I populate via a source model.

The population works fine, but I want the first option in the list to be "Select one...". I've used the following code:

```
$options[] = array(
  'label' => 'Select one...',
  'value' => '',
);
```

But the result is as follows:

[image: Duplicated empty item in select attribute]

With the rendered HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="">Select one...</option>
  <option data-title="Select one..." value="">Select one...</option>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

@awarche's answer works:

You'll need to add a caption to your UI  component field config:

`<item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select one...</item>`

I don't think an empty "Please select..." value belongs in a source model.

Answer (score 2):

So not sure how to do this with a label but if you just want a empty select you need to follow the core example and use an empty string:

vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php

```
/**
 * @param array $options
 * @return array
 */
private function addEmptyOption(array $options)
{
    array_unshift($options, ['label' => $this->getAttribute()->getIsRequired() ? '' : ' ', 'value' => '']);
    return $options;
}
```

i.e `'label' => ' ',`

Answer (score 1):

It works with **label** ' ' and **value** ''.

Maybe the **select field component has some restrictions** or rather a bug.

If you add the select attribute's values with `InstallData` or `UpgradeData` using the `'source'` property, you also need to include a space for the empty option's label.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace <yournamespace>\<yourmodule>\Helper;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class <YourProduct>ProductAttribute extends AbstractSource
{
    public const DEMO_ATTR = "demo_attr";

    public function getAllOptions(): ?array
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['label' => ' ', 'value' => ''],
                ['label' => 'First value', 'value' => 1],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Comment: The right way is to add caption to the select component `<item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select one...</item>`